# The algorithm of ListGraphs[n,m]

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics, implementation-details, combinatorica

I'm not sure if this is a Mathematica problem, math problem or a CS problem, so if this  is off-topic please transfer it.

In the package `Combinatorica` there is a function `ListGraphs[n,m]` which returns all nonisomorphic undirected graphs with `n` vertices and `m` edges. What algorithm does it use? All I can think of is to enumerate all graphs with `n` vertices and `m` edges brute-force, and check isomorphism for each graph. But I don't think that's effective. Is there a better algorism for this task? Thanks!

Comment: The `Combinatorica` package is described in detail in this book: [Computational Discrete Mathematics: Combinatorics and Graph Theory with Mathematica](http://www.amazon.com/Computational-Discrete-Mathematics-Combinatorics-Mathematica/dp/0521121469) .

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks for the recommendation! I checked but it's not in our library, so I might as well wait for an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the code for the function in the file `Combinatorica.m`:

```
nb = NotebookOpen[ToFileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "Packages", 
            "Combinatorica"}, "Combinatorica.m"]];
NotebookFind[nb, "ListGraphs[n_Integer?Positive, m_Integer]"]
```

[image]